# How to serialize GridLength as a part of user settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-serialization

I have a custom type, which has several `GridLength` properties. This type is a part of user settings. After saving the settings, my settings file looks like this:

```
                <MavEditor xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <RightSideWidth />
                    <LeftSideWidth />
                    <BottomSideHeight />
```

where `RightSideWidth`, `LeftSideWidth` and `BottomSideHeight` are `GridLength`.
Before saving settings I know, that their values are not `Auto`, but looks like XML serializer ignores this fact.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you talking about the standard .NET Application and User settings from `System.Configuration`? Those work well with a GridLength.

Comment: @Clemens: yes, this is WPF application and standard user settings mechanism. There shouldn't be any surprise with value types... but there is: debugger shows, that `Value` property has meaningful value, but `user.config` still contains empty tags after serialization.

Comment: Then what does the `<MavEditor xmlns:xsd ...` thing mean? My `user.config` files don't look like that.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but did you call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`?

Comment: @Clemens: yes, I call `Save`. `MavEditor` is a custom type, whose instance is contained within `Settings` type, this type has `GridLength` read/write properties. Serialization for the rest of properties of `MavEditor` works, as expected.

Comment: Looks like you have to implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface in your MavEditor class, and deserialize  the GridLengths by using a `GridLengthConverter`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this quick and dirty solution. Works, but may cause performance issues.

```
public GridLength Height
{
    // Create the "GridLength" from the separate properties
    get => new GridLength(this.Height_Value, (GridUnitType)Enum.Parse(typeof(GridUnitType), this.Height_GridUnitType));
    set
    {
        // store the "GridLength" properties in separate properties
        this.Height_GridUnitType = value.GridUnitType.ToString();
        this.Height_Value = value.Value;
    }
}

public string Height_GridUnitType { get; set; }
public double Height_Value{ get; set; }
```